# Change home page to an object in a subfolder

Tags: plone

How can I change the homepage for a plone site?

The closest thing I can find, is default_page under /portal_properties/site_properties in the ZMI. But it lists index.html and index.htm, which I find very confusing since there aren't any html files in a plone install.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Plone is a CMS and not server for solitary HTML files.

Comment: Change homepage to another object in a subfolder.

Comment: You can actually add an index.html or index.htm to the root of your Plone site (via the ZMI).  And since you have a default_page property, then Plone should render it.  I recall having tried this with Plone 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On siteroot add a contenttype 'Link', enter a title of your choice and set the destination to '/yourSiteId/yourSubfolder', make sure it is published, set the Link as default-view of your site.

In the subfolder set the content-item as defaultview.

Answer (score 1):

The "display" dropdown menu includes "select default item" which can be used to choose the object you wish to display as the default view of any  folder in a Plone site, including the home folder.

Comment: Thanks this is close to what I am after however it only allows content from the current folder, not others.

Comment: Plone is "folderish" i.e. place matters.  It is against the fundamental logic of Plone to use a content as your homepage that is not in your home folder.  This is an odd thing to want; what are you really trying to accomplish--perhaps we can suggest another way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Collage](http://plone.org/products/collage).  You can define a layout and then pick content items from any sub-folder and have it rendered within your collage layout.  You can then select your collage as the default view of your plone site (by selecting it as the default view).

The user interface for collage is a bit daunting but you should be able to get it after some trial and error.